SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to connect to Chrome using undetected_chromedriver
NOTE: It all works perfectly on my local machine, once I pushed it to the VPS, it stopped working.
I installed all dependencies, etc. IDK what else to do.
I am encountering a SessionNotCreatedException when trying to launch a Chrome browser using undetected_chromedriver in a Python script. The script is intended to log into a web application and fetch data. Below is the traceback of the error I am receiving:
Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/root/lsrp-discord-bot/setup_db.py", line 115, in \<module\
main()
File "/root/lsrp-discord-bot/setup_db.py", line 105, in main
driver = login_ucp()
^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/root/lsrp-discord-bot/setup_db.py", line 25, in login_ucp
driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=False,service=service)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/root/lsrp-discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/undetected_chromedriver/__init__.py", line 466, in __init__
super(Chrome, self).__init__(
File "/root/lsrp-discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
super().__init__(
File "/root/lsrp-discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 66, in __init__
super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
File "/root/lsrp-discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 212, in __init__
self.start_session(capabilities)
File "/root/lsrp-discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/undetected_chromedriver/__init__.py", line 724, in start_session
super(selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver, self).start_session(
File "/root/lsrp-discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 299, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)\["value"\]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/root/lsrp-discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 354, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/root/lsrp-discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:46647
from chrome not reachable
Stacktrace:
#0 0x55f65d8960aa \<unknown\
#1 0x55f65d3acffd \<unknown\
#2 0x55f65d3991ff \<unknown\
#3 0x55f65d3e82ec \<unknown\
#4 0x55f65d3de0da \<unknown\
#5 0x55f65d429ec6 \<unknown\
#6 0x55f65d429516 \<unknown\
#7 0x55f65d41db23 \<unknown\
#8 0x55f65d3ec990 \<unknown\
#9 0x55f65d3ed96e \<unknown\
#10 0x55f65d86216b \<unknown\
#11 0x55f65d865f68 \<unknown\
#12 0x55f65d84f64c \<unknown\
#13 0x55f65d866ae7 \<unknown\
#14 0x55f65d8344af \<unknown\
#15 0x55f65d8844f8 \<unknown\
#16 0x55f65d8846c0 \<unknown\
#17 0x55f65d894f26 \<unknown\
#18 0x7f35c6f56144 \<unknown\

^CTraceback (most recent call last):
File "/root/lsrp-discord-bot/setup_db.py", line 115, in \<module\
main()
File "/root/lsrp-discord-bot/setup_db.py", line 105, in main
driver = login_ucp()
^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/root/lsrp-discord-bot/setup_db.py", line 25, in login_ucp
driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=False,service=service)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/root/lsrp-discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/undetected_chromedriver/__init__.py", line 466, in __init__
super(Chrome, self).__init__(
File "/root/lsrp-discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
super().__init__(
File "/root/lsrp-discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 66, in __init__
super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
File "/root/lsrp-discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 212, in __init__
self.start_session(capabilities)
File "/root/lsrp-discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/undetected_chromedriver/__init__.py", line 724, in start_session
super(selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver, self).start_session(
File "/root/lsrp-discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 299, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)\["value"\]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/root/lsrp-discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 352, in execute
response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/root/lsrp-discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 306, in execute
return self.\_request(command_info\[0\], url, body=data)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/root/lsrp-discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 326, in \_request
response = self.\_conn.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/root/lsrp-discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/\_request_methods.py", line 143, in request
return self.request_encode_body(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/root/lsrp-discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/\_request_methods.py", line 278, in request_encode_body
return self.urlopen(method, url, \*\*extra_kw)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/root/lsrp-discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 443, in urlopen
response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, \*\*kw)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/root/lsrp-discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 789, in urlopen
response = self.\_make_request(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/root/lsrp-discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 536, in \_make_request
response = conn.getresponse()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/root/lsrp-discord-bot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 507, in getresponse
httplib_response = super().getresponse()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 1374, in getresponse
response.begin()
File "/usr/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 318, in begin
version, status, reason = self.\_read_status()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/lib/python3.11/http/client.py", line 279, in \_read_status
line = str(self.fp.readline(\_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/usr/lib/python3.11/socket.py", line 706, in readinto
return self.\_sock.recv_into(b)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Here's a snippet of the code I'm trying to run:
import time
import psutil
import json
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

UCP_USERNAME = 'x'
UCP_PASSWORD = 'x'

service = Service("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver", log_path="chromedriver.log")

def login_ucp():
    driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=False, service=service)  # Error occurs here
    Additional login logic...

def main():
    driver = login_ucp()
    Additional logic...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Environment

OS: Debian
Python version: 3.11.2
undetected_chromedriver version: 3.5.5
ChromeDriver version: 130.0.6723.58
Selenium version: 4.25.0
Chrome version: 130.0.6723.58

I've tried everything already, I just honestly don't know what to do anymore, I'm pretty much lost.
I know it has to do something with Selenium.
I tried making a file that just opens up the chrome using this

Please format the error, question, and your code before asking anything on SO https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Stacktrace:
#0 0x55cb638060aa <unknown>
#1 0x55cb6331d1a0 <unknown>
#2 0x55cb63369d06 <unknown>
#3 0x55cb63369fa1 <unknown>
#4 0x55cb633af344 <unknown>
#5 0x55cb6338ddad <unknown>
#6 0x55cb633ac866 <unknown>
#7 0x55cb6338db23 <unknown>
#8 0x55cb6335c990 <unknown>
#9 0x55cb6335d96e <unknown>
#10 0x55cb637d216b <unknown>
#11 0x55cb637d5f68 <unknown>
#12 0x55cb637bf64c <unknown>
#13 0x55cb637d6ae7 <unknown>
#14 0x55cb637a44af <unknown>
#15 0x55cb637f44f8 <unknown>
#16 0x55cb637f46c0 <unknown>
#17 0x55cb63804f26 <unknown>
#18 0x7f65a4ae8144 <unknown>

Getting this error now, fixed the one above...

Hello, this answer section is not for 'asking another, different question' check Why and how are some answers deleted? for detail. If you have another problem different one from this question page, you can post a new one. Thanks.

All good, problem solved. Thanks!
